# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in web crawling with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I've got an error while trying to crawl web data, the error message says

> Label info: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

The site is here
https://www.target.com/p/nong-shim-noodle-bowl-soup-spicy-kimchi-flavor-3-03oz/-/A-15137591#lnk=sametab

```
        try:
            label_info = soup.find('div', {'class': 'h-bg-white h-margin-a-default'})
            if debug: print('Label info:',label_info.text)
            if debug: print('')
        except Exception as e:
            label_info = ''
            if debug: print("Label info:", e)
            pass
```

Can anyone kindly guide me why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the CSS classes as a list of strings, instead of one string:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.target.com/p/nong-shim-noodle-bowl-soup-spicy-kimchi-flavor-3-03oz/-/A-15137591#lnk=sametab'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('div', {'class': ['h-bg-white', 'h-margin-a-default']}).get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
Highlights
Spicy kimchi flavor
Fresh noodle texture and robust flavor
Ready in only 3 minutes— just add hot water
Convenient on-the-go meal
```

Comment: Dang! you are my saviour, the point is that I need to include multiple classes as ['a', 'b', 'c'] !!!! Thanks very much @Andrej